# URL RewriteRule doesn't work when using WP Database Participants in my WordPress website

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, urls

I'm using WP Participants Database plugin in a site developed using WordPress and I'm trying to transform:

http://mysite.com/subfol1/subfol2/?listpage=3&search_field=none&value=&operator=LIKE&sortBy=denumire&ascdesc=asc&submit=&sortstring=denumire&orderstring=asc#participants-list

into

http://mysite.com/subfol1/subfol2/3/

My .htaccess is the one below:

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^produse/piese-schimb-utilaje-agricole/([0-9]+)/?$ ^produse/piese-schimb-utilaje-agricole/?listpage=$1&search_field=none&value=&operator=LIKE&sortBy=denumire&ascdesc=asc&submit=&sortstring=denumire&orderstring=asc#participants-list [NC,L]
```

My last RewriteRule does not work. Where did I went wrong?

Thank you for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try changing the order of your rules.  Once the default WP rules run, your URL will be rewritten and your last rule won't work.

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^produse/piese-schimb-utilaje-agricole/([0-9]+)/?$ ^produse/piese-schimb-utilaje-agricole/?listpage=$1&search_field=none&value=&operator=LIKE&sortBy=denumire&ascdesc=asc&submit=&sortstring=denumire&orderstring=asc#participants-list [NC,L]

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I moved the rule right before the commment in my code. Still it shows the same URL as before.